# How to conditionally set a reactive value with fileInput?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to upload either a csv file or an rds file and use it as the dataset for creating a table. I tried using a conditional `if/else`, but I'm getting this error: `argument is of length zero`. I would like to upload it outside of the renderTable as I like to use the reactive dataset for other purposes too.

Code

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("file_csv", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
            checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
            fileInput("file_rds", "Choose RDS File", accept = ".rds"),
        ),

        mainPanel(
           tableOutput("table1")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    dataset <- reactive({
        if(input$file_csv) {
            file <- input$file_csv
            ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
            
            req(file)
            validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
            
            read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
        } else {
            readRDS(file_rds$datapath)
        }
    })
    
    output$table1 <- renderTable({
        head(dataset())
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Attempt with `observeEvent` (not working):

```
    output$table1 <- renderTable({
        req(dataset())
        head(dataset())
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$file_csv, {
        dataset <- read.csv(input$file_csv$datapath, header = input$header)
    })
 
    observeEvent(input$file_rds, {
        dataset <- readRDS(input$file_rds$datapath)
    })
```

Attempt at rds file (not working):

```
       if(!is.null(input$file_rds )) {
            
            file <- input$file_rds
            req(file)
            
            readRDS(file$datapath)
            
            }
```

Comment: the `if(input$file_csv)` is not a logical condition here as `input$file_csv` can be empty or a string value

Comment: I generally start reactives like that with `req(input$file_csv)`, as it will preclude most problems like this.

Comment: I tried adding `req(input$file_csv)` but it didn't fix the logical issue pointed out by akrun. What is a good logical condition in this case?

Comment: I guess you may need `is.null` wrapped

Comment: I've tried another approach, but it didn't work. Please see update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  dataset <- reactive({
    req(input$file_csv)
    if(!is.null(input$file_csv )) {
      file <- input$file_csv
      ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
      
      req(file)
      validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
      
      read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    } else {
      readRDS(input$file_rds$datapath)
    }
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    head(dataset())
  })
}
```

- output

[image]

-validation check

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get the rds file working. Did it work for you?

Comment: I don't have an RDS file to check

Comment: I tried this: `saveRDS(mtcars, file = "mtcars.rds")`

Comment: @TyperWriter i think it must be related to updating the selectInput.  If you do the reverse, it works with readRDS i.e. `if(!is.null(input$file_rds ))`

Comment: @TyperWriter have you checked the soluiton in your own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68051688/how-to-restore-shiny-app-using-rda-file)