# Automatically restore the last Shiny Bookmark saved locally

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm using shiny apps in a automatized workflow, and therefore I want to be able to save the bookmark locally, and when opening the app in a future session, automatically restore the last saved bookmark (if available). I have two issues:

1. (*major*): the app currently does what I want, it automatically restores the last bookmark saved (if available). BUT when a bookmark gets restored the plot gets continuously updated. Probably I'm not getting the reactivity of the code right. Thanks!
2. (*minor*): ideally I would overwrite the saved bookmark, as I always just need the last one saved, so the saved files do not pile up over time. For now I only figured out how to retrieve the last one saved, which is ok, but I am happy to get suggestions on how to maybe do this.

*To reproduce the 1. issue, run the shiny app and click the bookmark button, than close the app, and then run it again.*

```r
library("shiny")
library("shinyjs")
library("tidyverse")

## module to do something with the data
shinyModuleUserInterface <- function(id, label) {
  ns <- NS(id) 
  tagList(
    titlePanel("Track of individual"),
    selectInput(inputId = ns("indv"), label = "Select indivdual", 
                choices = c("A","B","C"), selected="A"),
    plotOutput(ns("plot"))
  )
}

shinyModule <- function(input, output, session) { 
  ns <- session$ns 
  dataTrk <- data.frame(indv=rep(c("A","B","C"), each=4), 
                        x=c(1,4,2,6,9,5,3,8,9,4,3,7),
                        y=c(7,5,9,3,1,2,6,4,9,5,1,6))
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(y~x, dataTrk[dataTrk$indv==input$indv,], type="l")
  })
}

## function to get the last bookmark saved
get_last_bookmark <- function(){
  list.files(path = 'shiny_bookmarks/') %>% 
    map_df(., ~paste0('shiny_bookmarks/', .x) %>%
             file.info) %>%
    slice_max(atime) %>%
    rownames()
}
get_last_bookmark <- possibly(get_last_bookmark, otherwise = '') #avoid empty folder error

## main app code
ui <- function(request) { 
  fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    shinyModuleUserInterface("shinyModule"),
    bookmarkButton()
  )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  callModule(shinyModule,"shinyModule")
  
  onBookmarked(function(state){
    # avoid showing popup message window as I just want the bookmark to be saved locally
  })
  
  ## below my intention is: check if there is a stored bookmark available, if yes, restore the last bookmark
  observeEvent(req(get_last_bookmark() !=""), {
    sessionName <- get_last_bookmark() %>% str_sub(17, -1)
    restoreURL  <- paste0(session$clientData$url_protocol, "//",
                          session$clientData$url_hostname, ":",
                          session$clientData$url_port, "/?_state_id_=",
                          sessionName)
    # redirect user to restoreURL
    shinyjs::runjs(sprintf("window.location = '%s';", restoreURL))
  }, once = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server,enableBookmarking="server")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the above code is, that `shinyjs::runjs(sprintf("window.location = '%s';", restoreURL))` triggers a new shiny session once a bookmark is found but it doesn't check whether the running session already was restored from that bookmark (so we end up in a restoring loop). Please check my modified `req` call in the upper `observeEvent`.

The lower `observeEvent` deletes the bookmark file and folder after it was restored (referring to the initial answer)

**2. Edit:**

This is a more robust approach which is moving the latest bookmark always into the same folder:

```
library(fs)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

## module to do something with the data
shinyModuleUserInterface <- function(id, label) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    titlePanel("Track of individual"),
    selectInput(
      inputId = ns("indv"),
      label = "Select indivdual",
      choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
      selected = "A"
    ),
    plotOutput(ns("plot"))
  )
}

shinyModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns
  dataTrk <- data.frame(
    indv = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4),
    x = c(1, 4, 2, 6, 9, 5, 3, 8, 9, 4, 3, 7),
    y = c(7, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 9, 5, 1, 6)
  )
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(y ~ x, dataTrk[dataTrk$indv == input$indv, ], type = "l")
  })
}

## main app code
ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(shinyModuleUserInterface("shinyModule"),
            bookmarkButton())
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(session, {
    if(file_exists(path("shiny_bookmarks/latest/input.rds")) && is.null(parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)$`_state_id_`)){
      updateQueryString(queryString = "?_state_id_=latest")
      session$reload() 
    }
  }, once = TRUE)
  
  callModule(shinyModule, "shinyModule")

  onBookmarked(function(url) {
    # avoid showing popup message window as I just want the bookmark to be saved locally
    # we could use urltools::url_parse(url)$parameter instead of sub()
    if(!dir_exists("shiny_bookmarks/latest")){
      dir_create("shiny_bookmarks/latest")
    }
    file_move(path = path("shiny_bookmarks", parseQueryString(sub("^.*\\?", "", url))$`_state_id_`, "input.rds"), new_path = path("shiny_bookmarks/latest/input.rds"))
    dir_delete(path("shiny_bookmarks", parseQueryString(sub("^.*\\?", "", url))$`_state_id_`))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

---

**Edit:**

This avoids using `shinyjs` by using `updateQueryString`:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

## module to do something with the data
shinyModuleUserInterface <- function(id, label) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    titlePanel("Track of individual"),
    selectInput(
      inputId = ns("indv"),
      label = "Select indivdual",
      choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
      selected = "A"
    ),
    plotOutput(ns("plot"))
  )
}

shinyModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns
  dataTrk <- data.frame(
    indv = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4),
    x = c(1, 4, 2, 6, 9, 5, 3, 8, 9, 4, 3, 7),
    y = c(7, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 9, 5, 1, 6)
  )
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(y ~ x, dataTrk[dataTrk$indv == input$indv, ], type = "l")
  })
}

## function to get the last bookmark saved
get_last_bookmark <- function() {
  list.files(path = 'shiny_bookmarks/') %>%
    map_df(., ~ paste0('shiny_bookmarks/', .x) %>%
             file.info) %>%
    slice_max(atime) %>%
    rownames()
}
get_last_bookmark <- possibly(get_last_bookmark, otherwise = '') #avoid empty folder error

## main app code
ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(shinyModuleUserInterface("shinyModule"),
            bookmarkButton())
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(shinyModule, "shinyModule")
  
  onBookmarked(function(state) {
    # avoid showing popup message window as I just want the bookmark to be saved locally
  })
  
  observeEvent(req(get_last_bookmark() != "" && is.null(parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)$`_state_id_`)), {
    bookmarkName <- basename(get_last_bookmark())
    updateQueryString(queryString = paste0("?_state_id_=", bookmarkName))
    session$reload()
  }, once = TRUE)
  
  # also see ?onRestored()
  observeEvent(session$clientData$url_search, {
    if (!is.null(parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)$`_state_id_`)) {
      if (basename(get_last_bookmark()) == parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)$`_state_id_`) {
        fs::dir_delete(get_last_bookmark())
      }
    }
  }, once = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

---

**Initial answer** using `shinyjs`:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyjs")
library("tidyverse")

## module to do something with the data
shinyModuleUserInterface <- function(id, label) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    titlePanel("Track of individual"),
    selectInput(
      inputId = ns("indv"),
      label = "Select indivdual",
      choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
      selected = "A"
    ),
    plotOutput(ns("plot"))
  )
}

shinyModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  ns <- session$ns
  dataTrk <- data.frame(
    indv = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 4),
    x = c(1, 4, 2, 6, 9, 5, 3, 8, 9, 4, 3, 7),
    y = c(7, 5, 9, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 9, 5, 1, 6)
  )
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(y ~ x, dataTrk[dataTrk$indv == input$indv, ], type = "l")
  })
}

## function to get the last bookmark saved
get_last_bookmark <- function() {
  list.files(path = 'shiny_bookmarks/') %>%
    map_df(., ~ paste0('shiny_bookmarks/', .x) %>%
             file.info) %>%
    slice_max(atime) %>%
    rownames()
}
get_last_bookmark <-
  possibly(get_last_bookmark, otherwise = '') #avoid empty folder error

## main app code
ui <- function(request) {
  fluidPage(useShinyjs(),
            shinyModuleUserInterface("shinyModule"),
            bookmarkButton())
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(shinyModule, "shinyModule")
  
  onBookmarked(function(state) {
    # avoid showing popup message window as I just want the bookmark to be saved locally
  })
  
  observeEvent(req(get_last_bookmark() != "" && is.null(parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)$`_state_id_`)), {
    sessionName <- get_last_bookmark() %>% str_sub(17,-1)
    restoreURL  <- paste0(
      session$clientData$url_protocol, "//",
      session$clientData$url_hostname, ":",
      session$clientData$url_port, "/?_state_id_=",
      sessionName
    )
    # redirect user to restoreURL
    shinyjs::runjs(sprintf("window.location = '%s';", restoreURL))
  }, once = TRUE)

  # also see ?onRestored()
  observeEvent(session$clientData$url_search, {
    if (!is.null(parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)$`_state_id_`)) {
      if (basename(get_last_bookmark()) == parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)$`_state_id_`) {
        fs::dir_delete(get_last_bookmark())
      }
    }
  }, once = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

Deleting the bookmark files might lead to:

> Error in RestoreContext initialization: Bookmarked state directory
> does not exist.
> if the old bookmarking query string is still present in the browsers address bar.

As an alternative to the above approach please check the libraries library([shinyStore](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyStore)) or library([shinyStorePlus](https://github.com/oobianom/shinyStorePlus)) which use the browsers [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage?retiredLocale=de) to restore shiny inputs.

Please also check my earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267644/it-is-possible-to-restore-a-session-locally-in-a-shiny-app-if-the-inputs-have/68253464#68253464).

[Here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/changing-bookmark-state-directory-when-saving-to-disk/37877/2) is another related question and [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2537) a related GitHub issue.