# In Shiny/R how to drag and drop and save state

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I need to send a the link of my app to a client.

I will ask him to change de positions of the images (the images are inside the html divs).
After he/she decide the order of positions he will save the state.

And then I will see how he ordered the images.

The app is deployed on Shinyapps.io

How can I do this process in shiny? Is it related with saving states?

This is the code:

### ---- bucket-list-app -----------------------------------------------

### Example shiny app with bucket list

```
library(shiny)
library(sortable)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".bucket-list-container {min-height: 350px;}"),
               ),
    tags$style(
      "#rank_list_1,
      #rank_list_2{
      display: flex;
      }
      "
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      tags$b("Exercise"),
      width = 12,
      bucket_list(
        header = "Drag the items in any desired bucket",
        group_name = "bucket_list_group",
        orientation = "horizontal",
        add_rank_list(
          text = "Drag from here",
          input_id = "rank_list_1",
          labels = list(
            htmltools::tags$div(
              "Div 1"
            ),
            htmltools::tags$div(
              "Div 2"
            ),
            htmltools::tags$div(
              "Div 3"
            ),
            htmltools::tags$div(
              "Div 4"
            )
          )
        ),add_rank_list(
          text = "to here",
          labels = NULL,
          input_id = "rank_list_2"
        ))))

      )

server <- function(input, output, session) {


}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help?

Comment: I assume by "save state" you mean save it in a way that you or they can then access those states later, perhaps after the shiny app closes and/or restarts. In that case, find a SQL or NoSQL solution, perhaps `RSQLite`, `duckdb`, a more formal SQL DBMS, Redis, MongoDB, RabbitMQ, or any number of other options (I'm explicitly not suggesting a simple text file storage for a few reasons, but that is always possible). Since you're deploying this to shinyapps.io, though, the file-based solutions will have some problems, so ... likely something else.

Comment: @r2evans thanks as always for your time! Do you know any material that would help me to do this task?

Comment: First, for clarity, I think you need to be more specific as to your requirements. Do you need it to persist for one user only (perhaps hackable with HTML5 web-storage api, not sure), for that user and the admin (you), or for multiple users? Are you hoping to gain access to the results of the users' efforts immediately (near real-time) or in batches (when you can get to it)? How much data is there to save, and in what structure/schema? As for material to help you ... this is a little multi-domain (at least shiny+database), but look for "shiny persistent data storage".

Comment: For instance, Dean is a shiny expert and has spoken about this topic in https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/persistent-data-storage/. Other discussions such as https://community.rstudio.com/t/persistent-data-storage-in-apps-with-multiple-users/1308. Unfortunately, that's a bigger problem to solve than a simple StackOverflow question ...

Comment: All correct words from @r2evans. First of all, take a look here <https://yang-tang.github.io/shinyjqui/articles/save-and-restore.html>. The main issue with shinyapps.io is the inability to write on the server. Otherwise, we could save the state in an .Rdata file, as shown here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77189728/how-can-i-dynamically-create-and-save-user-defined-combinations-in-r-shiny-and-s>, and in the accompanying posts, as well as here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922190/saving-state-of-shiny-app-to-be-restored-later>. In the end, I solved the issue using Google Sheets!